# How synchronize two disks (or folders) using symbolic (or hard) links (like rsync)?

Tags: linux, algorithm, shell, symbolic-link

I'm searching a **tool** or a **shell script** or **another program** to synchronize two or more folders or disks.

But it differs of rsync tool, because, I don't want to duplicate the missing file, but do a symbolic link of it in the other folder, for example:

If in folder ***A*** we have the files ***a*** and ***b*** and other folder ***c*** with a file ***d***:

> A
>
> > a
> >
> > b
> >
> > c
> >
> > > d

And in folder ***B*** we have the file ***1*** and a folder ***2*** with a file ***3***:

> B
>
> > 1
> >
> > 2
> >
> > > 3

I would like program, for example, *ssync* (symbolic synchronize, just a invention name), called by a command, for example, ***ssync /A /B*** to change these folders like showed below:

> A
>
> > a
> >
> > b
> >
> > c
> >
> > > d
> >
> > 1 (ln -s)
> >
> > 2 (ln -s)
> >
> > > 3 (ln -s)

and

> B
>
> > 1
> >
> > 2
> >
> > > 3
> >
> > a (ln -s)
> >
> > b (ln -s)
> >
> > c (ln -s)
> >
> > > d (ln -s)

where ***ln -s*** indicates that in this folder was created a symbolic link to this corresponding file, for example, ***a (ln -s)*** indicates the command ***ln -s /A/a /B/a*** was used.

Another thing can happen, if the file and the link have the same name, the link should have a different name automatically too...

I will appreciate so much if someone help me. Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS could be worth considering, but I dont know your specific use-case. If you are into programming look for a "directory walk" function of some sort. I think it will get a little complicated.

Comment: Hum...thx about the answer, unfortunally, I would like a program to use in ext4 filesystem. Do you know something like that to ext4?

Comment: This is a good question, but I think it should be better answered if you ask it in ServerFault.

Comment: Question also exists on [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22735/4667)

Comment: My first thought would have been `cp -rpn  /B/* /A` and then delete `/B` and finally, `ln -s /A /B`. But I know you're looking for something more complicated (perhaps the directories are in different file systems?).

Comment: No, just in ext4 filesystems, but in diferente disks.

Comment: Its a interesting attempt, however the folder A should keep all the files...if you didnt have space in disk its not possible =//

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Arcege](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4194/arcege) answer to me in [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22735/how-synchronize-two-disks-or-folders-using-symbolic-or-hard-links-like-rsyn/22742#22742) the answer is below.

Thx very much [Arcege](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4194/arcege)!

If someone improve a bit more this script, please post an answer too =).

Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
srcdir="$1"
dstdir="$2"
if [ -h "$srcdir" ]; then
    val=`readlink "$srcdir"`
    if [ ! -h "$dstdir" ]; then
        rm -rf "$dstdir"
    fi
    ln -s "$val" "$dstdir"
elif [ -d "$srcdir" ]; then
    if [ ! -d "$dstdir" ]; then
        rm -rf "$dstdir"
    fi
    mkdir "$dstdir"
    for i in `ls -1A "$srcdir"`; do
        $0 "$srcdir/$i" "$dstdir/$i"
    done
    touch -a -r "$srcdir" "$dstdir"
    touch -m -r "$srcdir" "$dstdir"
else
    if [ ! -f "$dstdir" ]; then
        rm -rf "$dstdir"
    fi
    ln "$srcdir" "$dstdir"
fi
```

This doesn't handle "special" files like block devices, named pipes, sockets, etc..